# Lebesgue-integrability of piecewise function with random variable

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

This function is Lebesgue-integrable:$$\chi(x)= \left\{
     \begin{array}{ll}
       1 & \text{if}~x~\text{is rational}\\
       0 & \text{if}~x~\text{is irrational}.
     \end{array}
   \right.$$

¿But is this function:$$\chi_2(x)= \left\{
     \begin{array}{ll}
       x & \text{if}~x~\text{is rational}\\
       -x & \text{if}~x~\text{is irrational}
     \end{array}
   \right.$$?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by $rand(0,1)$ and how it is a function of $x$.  For example, what would the function $f(x)=rand(0,1)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ mean?  Does it change with $x$? Does it depend on something other than $x$?

Comment: @Michael It is random, meaning: It doesn't correlate with $x$.

Comment: That is not enough info.  You need to specify it as a function of $x$.

Comment: @Michael I've change my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Q of whether a function is Lebesgue-measurable or Lebesgue-integrable is unaffected by what values the function takes on any one set that has Lebesgue measure zero.Every countable (meaning finite or countably infinite) set of reals is Lebesgue-null (meaning that its Lebesgue measure is zero.) The set of rationals is countable, hence it's Lebesgue-null.Let g(x)=-x for all x. Then $\chi_2$ and g are equal except on a Lebesgue-null set, and g is measurable so $\chi_2$ is.